# Doing 1+ async API calls before doing final async API

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a iOS app where at a given moment I have do 1+ async api calls which needs to be completed before I can send the final async call to my server. What is the best way to do it? e.g.

Start

1. async call to server 1
2. async call to server 2
3. wait for #1 and #2 to get over before async call to server 3

I am using Obj-c

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try to [search for a way how to achieve this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=objective-c%20wait%20for%20async%20task)? Many ways. Show some effort and code which doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As zrzka points out there are many ways to do this. Here is one suggestion.

Use an `NSOperationQueue` and set async call to server 1 and 2 as dependencies on call to server 3. Here is an outline.

```
NSOperationQueue * queue = ...

// s1, s2 and s3 are blocks that do your work
NSOperation * server1 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:s1];
NSOperation * server2 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:s2];
NSOperation * server3 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:s3];

[server3 addDependency:server1];
[server3 addDependency:server2];

// Now you can schedule
[queue addOperation:server1];
[queue addOperation:server2];
[queue addOperation:server3];
```